# How can I know the number of developers who do not have a Stack Overflow account and answered the 2016 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I got the 2016 Developer Survey data, but I don't know how I can get the number of  developers who do not have a Stack Overflow account and answered this survey. I also would like to know their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Out of the total 56,033 participants, only 27,938 gave their profile ID with the survey. (As stated at [Developer Survey Results
2016 — Community III. Asking and Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#community-asking-and-answering)). You can see the relevant user reputation and question statistics for the users that *did* provide their profile ID, but you're unlikely to get anything more than that.

You can see from [Developer Survey Results
2016 — Community I. Visit Frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#community-visit-frequency) that 0.8% answered: "I have never been on Stack Overflow. I just love taking surveys." So it's obvious *some* respondents don't have Stack Overflow accounts, but again only 46,165 out of 56,033 answered that question. So the information you want doesn't really exist, at least not completely or conclusively. What does exist you should be able to see from the results.

Comment: (interestingly 43.6% of the respondents who did give their Stack Overflow profile ID had 100 or less reputation).